# Trying to combine count and left join

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, subquery, left-join

I have three tables, each with only one column I care about for the purpose of this query:

```
Table A 
**Color**
Red
Blue 
Green
Purple

Table B
**Color**
Pink
Black
Blue
Green
Blue
Green

Table C
**Color**
Orange 
Purple
Purple
Red
```

I want to do a left join of A with B and C and get a count for each color.  I want a result that looks like this:

```
Color CountA CountB CountC
Red    1      0      1
Blue   1      2      0
Green  1      2      0
Purple 1      0      2
```

When I do the count with the inner join, it adds up some weird numbers.  I think it is something with my GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/484bf1/3/0)

```
SELECT Color,
(
  SELECT Count(*) 
  FROM TableA a
  WHERE a.Color = m.color
) AS CountA,
(
  SELECT Count(*) 
  FROM TableB b
  WHERE b.Color = m.color
) AS CountB,
(
  SELECT Count(*) 
  FROM TableC c
  WHERE c.Color = m.color
) AS CountC
FROM TableA m
GROUP BY m.Color;
```

Comment: I am getting a "disk:I/O error".  Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: It could be a lot of things.  Try enabling and checking the [**error log**](http://www.sqlite.org/errlog.html)

Comment: I got that worked out.  However, the query returns a result that is not deduped.

Comment: Add the `GROUP BY` like in my answer that I just edited.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make two points.  The first may be a more efficient way to write the query:

```
SELECT Color, Count(*) as CountA,
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM TableB b
        WHERE b.Color = a.color
       ) AS CountB,
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM TableC c
        WHERE c.Color = a.color
       ) AS CountC
FROM TableA a
GROUP BY a.Color;
```

Note that if A has no duplicates, a better way is:

```
SELECT Color, 1 as CountA
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM TableB b
        WHERE b.Color = a.color
       ) AS CountB,
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM TableC c
        WHERE c.Color = a.color
       ) AS CountC
FROM TableA a;
```

That is, remove the group by.

The second point is that an index on tableB(color) and tableC(color) will help performance,

Comment: I just threw it in excel to remove the duplicates.  The counts were correct, it just repeated them various numbers of times.

Comment: Now if there was a second column in every table that had a number associated with each color and I wanted to place the same query, but instead of just counting all the numbers for red, I wanted to add them up... what would that query look like?

Comment: You would use sum() instead of count() in the subqueries.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you all so much!  Also, just entering distinct prior to color will filter the result set and remove duplicates.